# Capacitor as a battery in a tablet

Tags: power

I got it from here years ago.

https://www.walmart.com/ip/EVOO-10-1-Tablet-Keyboard-Dual-Core-Intel-Processor-32GB-Storage-Windows-Ink-Smart-Stylus-included-Micro-HDMI-Cameras-10-Home-Black/455610609

I installed Ubuntu Server on it with the one USB going out to a SSD.

It was working real good for over a year but then the battery puffed up and snap off the back of it. It doesn't work any more.

I removed the battery and already took it to a hazardous waste dump. I got a photo of it before I did.

Here is the photo on my Google drive.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/DCwJ8gQYGFYAN1X77

I soldered a 6.3 volt capacitor on the little thin long board that battery was on.

I got this photo of it.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/XmvDFvHTG8mghQuc6

The four pads on the other side of this strip were the battery was I got the white wire to one of the center ones. They were both shorted out so I guess that is the ground and have it to the ground of the capacitor.

The black wires I put one both ends I guess that was the battery's plus side.

When I plug in the power all that happens is a red LED on the top of the screen comes on. I can hold down the power button but it never turns on.

Will this work? Maybe need some other type of capacitor?

I am just going to have this plug in the power all the time so don't need it to have a battery.

Comment: What makes you think that a capacitor would be able to replace the function of the battery? The battery is 7.4 V yet you think using a 6.3 V capacitor will be OK? The laptop looks could be designed such that it always needs a battery present. The same is true for many smartphones. Your best bet is to get a replacement battery. You could use two 3.7 V pouch cells in series. Realize that the new batteries might also build up pressure. The laptop doesn't look like it is treating the batteries like it should.

Comment: I know I can get another replacement battery but in just over a year it will need to be replaced again. I thought the 6.3 V capacitor would charge up real fast and it see it as a battery and just use it like that. Maybe I do need a 7.4 V capacitor then.

Comment: *I thought the 6.3 V capacitor would charge up real fast and it see it as a battery and just use it like that.* You'd have to have a really, really high capacitor value for that. Anything less and the capacitor is empty in a fraction of a second. You're over estimating how much energy a "normal" capacitor can store. You would need a capacitor in the order of 0.1 F (that's 100.000 uF). It would take a while to charge....

Comment: ... Such capacitors don't exist for use at 7.4 V. You can make your own with several super caps in series and some electronics. That would cost the same as a new battery. And it would not fit in your laptop either. You'd need an extra bag and a wire between laptop and bag with capacitors.

Comment: Weird. My computer used to work when battery removed. Are you sure you need a capacitor to start the laptop?

Comment: There's got to be some way to power thing to not use a battery. I guess need a schematic to know how to change it so just powers up from the plug.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: if it were possible to power a consumer product with a  capacitor instead of a battery, the industry would have already done it.

Long answer: capacitors and batteries have different strengths, making one appropriate for some applications, and the other for other applications. Capacitors can receive and deliver short bursts of high power (such as 100 W in < 1 second). Batteries can receive and deliver continuous amounts of low power (such as 1 W > 1 hour).

A tablet computer needs continuous amounts of low power. Hence, it needs a battery. Not a capacitor.

Comment: The industry *has* already done it, it's just that it's not suitable for a majority of purposes. Batteries are much more energy-dense than capacitors and have lower leakage.

Comment: Yes I know they don't use capacitors. I don't even want to use a battery. Just want to use power from the wall. Just thought the capacitor would be like a little battery because if I put a power supply for the battery it will want to charge it. So I thought a capacitor my work. It is a tablet but all so a computer and keeping it in the same place at home so it don't need a battery that can go bad with time.

Comment: The power supply to this is a 12 volt 2 amp one. So I guess the battery's there were 2 each 7.6 volt that would add up to 15.2 volts. Or maybe that long narrow bard at the top of the 2 buttery's converts it to 12 volts.

Comment: Just solder from wires from the power supply to the battery. So it's 12 volts going to the battery and Wow it boots up now without the battery.

Comment: But after about 13 hours it turns off!

Comment: The last thing I did on the command line was this.

Comment: raymond@ray-tablet:~$ upower -i $(upower -e | grep BAT) | grep --color=never -E "state|to\ full|to\ empty|percentage"
    state:               discharging
    time to empty:       9.7 minutes
    percentage:          15%
raymond@ray-tablet:~$ uptime
 06:14:21 up 13:27,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
raymond@ray-tablet:~$

Comment: The wight wire to the battery I just left maybe if I solder it to ground it will not think the battery is discharging?